# Why does ls show this file twice with different sizes?

Tags: rhel, configuration, openssh

Why is 50-redhat.conf listed twice with different file sizes for this directory with this ls:

ls -la /etc/ssh/ssh*

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root         1921 Aug  2 02:58 /etc/ssh/ssh_config
-rw-------. 1 root root         3667 Aug  2 02:58 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys      480 May 20 02:38 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root          162 May 20 02:38 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys      387 May 20 02:38 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root           82 May 20 02:38 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys     2578 May 20 02:38 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root          554 May 20 02:38 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root           28 Aug  4 10:14 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root         4096 Aug  4 10:14 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root          581 Aug  2 02:58 50-redhat.conf

/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d:
total 8
drwx------. 2 root root           28 Aug  4 10:14 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root         4096 Aug  4 10:14 ..
-rw-------. 1 root root          719 Aug  2 02:58 50-redhat.conf
```

Comment: One appears to be in ssh_config.d and the other in ssh**d**_config.d

Comment: These are two different files ind two different directories.

Comment: Add the `-i` option to your `ls -la` command, and you'll see that the files have different inodes, and therefore they are different files.  Files in different directories can have the same name as each other.  Unique names are needed when they're in the same directory.

Comment: @SottoVoce, the different sizes and permissions also reveal they're two different files (inodes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two files are different.  The one occurring in `ssh_config.d` contains SSH client configuration.  The one found in `sshd_config.d` contains SSH server configuration.